scala.MatchError: null - why does pattern match fails?
Construct a function to return the default value of any type:
import scala.compiletime.uninitialized
def default[T]:T = {
    class Default[T] { var value:T = uninitialized }

    Default[T].value
}
default[Double]   // Double = 0.0
default[Boolean]  // Boolean = false
default[Int]      // Int = 0

This pattern match does not work (why?):
def matchType[T]():T = {
    default[T] match {
        case d:Double => d
        case i:Int => i
        case b:Boolean => b
    }
}

matchType[Double]()

scala.MatchError: null
  ammonite.$sess.cmd37$.matchType(cmd37.sc:5)
  ammonite.$sess.cmd37$.<clinit>(cmd37.sc:9)

Why is the pattern match failing?
In both cases (top case: using default[Double] and bottom case: using matchTypeDouble) everything is known at compile time.

I don't really understand why you need this default thing for the use case you describe. Sounds like a typeclass could be enough.

@GaëlJ correct I writing a type class for what motivating the question. In writing type class I came across the problem and I'm trying understanding more about types as a new Scala writer. So I still am asking why it happen with the default[T] function - if that make sense? Maybe I remove the "Motivation for this question" comment if it confusing? I edit it out

@GaëlJ I put "Motivation for this question" comment here so it don't confuse in main question:  Motivation for this question: convert a string to a type where you specify the type T, then use pattern match to handle different functionality at runtime. e.g. fromStringToDouble would pattern match on the Double (using default[Double]) and use functionality at runtime to convert "3.14" to 3.14:Double using e.g. toString

don't worry, this was just a comment in case you were more interested in a way to solve your functional problem. There's nothing wrong in wanting to understand a technical "issue" you discover along the way :)

If I had to guess, I think the issue is related to type erasure of T: at runtime default[T] has an unknown T.

Pattern matching does not work on generic types due to type erasure, but this issue is casued by a null value. For whatever reason the the pattern matching is getting a null value and then it is failing to match as none of the match cases handle null. Which Scala version is this ?

@sarveshseri I using com.lihaoyi:ammonite_3.4.2:3.0.0-M2-13-23a8ef64 so it Scala 3.4.2. Funny I also notice
@ default[Double]
res117: Double = 0.0
@ println(default[Double])
null
I will read on type erasure

@GeorgeChen Yes, It is good to understand type erarure. But you issue is not related to it.  It is interesting that the same default[Double] is both 0.0 and null at the same time. Seems like a bug in Scala 3.
